# Taylor expansion of $x^2(t)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This function for air resistance (drag) supposedly shows a Taylor expansion. I understand the basics of Taylor expansion, but can't see how I would get this answer. If someone could elaborate and explain the intermediate steps and how these last terms should be understood it would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: If you could comment and not just downvote I'd love to attempt to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let f be a function. If we have that $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, we have that
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+r(x)$$
With
$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{r(x)}{x-a}=0$$
So around $a$, we have the best linear approximation if we neglect $r$:
$$f(x) \approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$$

In your problem, we have that $f$ is a function of the velocity $v$: $f(v)=Cv^2$. If we pick a velocity $v_a$, we have the following approximation around $v_0$:
$$f(v) \approx f(v_a) + f'(v_a)(v-v_a)$$
$$Cv^2 \approx Cv_a^2+\left.\frac{\mathrm{d} (Cv^2)}{\mathrm{d}v}\right|_{v=v_a}(v-v_a)$$
So we have what you wanted.

Comment: I see how $r(t)$ -> $0$,  but why you divide $r(t)$ on $(t-t_0)$ ?  And I see how you get $f'(t)(t-t_0)$, but how $(t-t0)$ equal $\Delta$$v(t)$ ?

Comment: @bretddog Is it better now?

Comment: @bretddog The $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{r(x)}{x-a}=0$ means something like "$r$ is really small around $a$, because it goes to $0$ even if we divide it by $x-a$". It's just an equivalent definition of the differentiability: We say that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $a \in \text{int}(\text{dom}(f))$, if there exists $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r: \text{dom}(f) \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{r(x)}{x-a}=0$ so that $f$ has the form $f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+r(x)$.

Comment: Great! that helped a lot. "$int(dom($" does that mean integer domain? In case why should it be int?

Comment: @bretddog $\text{int}(A)$ is the interior of the set $A$. So $\text{int}(\text{dom}(f))$ is the interior of the domain of the $f$.